# SQLAlchemy: how to create new tables in an existing database using declarative base?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a test database with two entities: post and category and I'm using declarative base to perform the manipulation of the data in my base, as follows:

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"

    post_id = Column('id', primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title')
  ...other attributes...

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = "category"

    category_id = Column('id', primary_key=True)
    description = Column('name')
  ...other attributes...
```

Assuming I wanted to create a relationship between post and category (which does not exist in my database), how do I create it? Any idea?

Edit1:

I'll try to be clearer: the database already exists where a bind is done, as well as the post and category tables. What I want is to create a relationship between them through the code and write this in the database

Answer (score 0):

`create_all` method support specify tables to create:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(tables=[Post.__table__,])
```

result:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> .tables
post
```

Comment: That's not what I need. I'll try to be clearer: the database already exists where a bind is done, as well as the post and category tables. What I want is to create a relationship between them through the code and write this in the database

Comment: @Oliveira check out alembic